# Image merger showing that cGAN doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision

**Merge Image Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog, Label, Button
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

# preprocessing of image
def preprocessing_image(image, path):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (64, 64))
    image = image/255.0
    return np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

#generate output image
def generate_output_image(model, input_image1, input_image2):
    latent_space1 = model.predict(input_image1)
    latent_space2 = model.predict(input_image2)
    alpha = 0.5
    interpolated_latent_space = alpha * latent_space1 + (1-alpha) * latent_space2
    mixed_image = model.layers[-1].predict(interpolated_latent_space)
    return mixed_image

# handeling image selection and merging
def merge_images():
    # tkinter window opened
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Image Merger")
    
    # label display while merge loading status
    loading_label = Label(root, text="Loading. . . . .", padx=20, pady=20)
    
    # func to load and merge images
    def load_and_merge_images():
        image1_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Image 1", filetypes=[("image Files", "*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg")])
        image2_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Image 2", filetypes=[("image Files", "*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg")])
        
        if image1_path and image2_path:
            loading_label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2) # display loading message
            
            image1 = preprocessing_image(image1_path)
            image2 = preprocessing_image(image2_path)
            
            mixed_image = generate_output_image(gan_model, image1, image2)
            mixed_image = (mixed_image.squeeze()*255).astype(np.uint8)
            
            # saving mixed image
            mixed_image_path = "mixed_image.jpg"
            cv2.imwrite(mixed_image_path, cv2.cvtColor(mixed_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
            
            loading_label.grid () # remove the loading message
            display_button.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2) # display 'open image' button
            
            # display original images and generated image
            cv2.imshow('image 1', cv2.cvtColor(image1.squeeze(), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
            cv2.imshow('image 2', cv2.cvtColor(image2.squeeze(), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
            cv2.imshow('Mixed Image', cv2.cvtColor(mixed_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
            
    # func to open generated mixed image
    def open_image():
        cv2.imshow('Mixed Image', cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("mixed_image.jpg"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RBG))
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        
    # button to start merging process
    merge_button = Button(root, text="Merge Image", command=load_and_merge_images)
    merge_button.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
    
    # button to open generated image
    display_button = Button(root, text="Open Image", command=open_image)
    
    root.mainloop()
    
# load GAN model
gan_model = load_model(r'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\OpenCV\merge img\cGAN.py.h5')
# start merge process
merge_images()
```

**cGAN code:**

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, LeakyReLU, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

def load_dataset(folder_path):
    input_images = []
    target_images = []

    for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if file_name.startswith("input_"):
            input_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
            target_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name.replace("input_", "target_"))

            input_image = cv2.imread(input_path)
            target_image = cv2.imread(target_path)

            # Resize images if needed
            input_image = cv2.resize(input_image, (64, 64))
            target_image = cv2.resize(target_image, (64, 64))

            input_images.append(input_image / 255.0)
            target_images.append(target_image / 255.0)

    return np.array(input_images), np.array(target_images)

# Replace 'your_dataset_folder' with the path to your dataset
input_images, target_images = load_dataset(r'C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\archive (1)')

# cGAN to generate conditioning
def build_cgan_model(input_shape):
    generator = build_generator(input_shape)
    discriminator = build_discriminator(input_shape)

    input_image = Input(shape=input_shape)
    conditioning_image = Input(shape=input_shape)

    generated_image = generator([input_image, conditioning_image])

    discriminator.trainable = False
    validity = discriminator([generated_image, conditioning_image])

    cgan_model = Model(inputs=[input_image, conditioning_image], outputs=validity)
    cgan_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0002, beta_1=0.5), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return cgan_model

# building generator and discrimination
def build_generator(input_shape):
    # Define generator architecture
    # ...

    return generator

def build_discriminator(input_shape):
    # Define discriminator architecture
    # ...

    return discriminator

# Training model
def train_cgan(generator, discriminator, cgan_model, input_images, conditioning_images, target_images, epochs, batch_size):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Randomly select batch samples
        idx = np.random.randint(0, input_images.shape[0], batch_size)
        input_batch = input_images[idx]
        conditioning_batch = conditioning_images[idx]
        target_batch = target_images[idx]

        # Generate fake images using the generator
        generated_images = generator.predict([input_batch, conditioning_batch])

        # Train the discriminator
        d_loss_real = discriminator.train_on_batch([target_batch, conditioning_batch], np.ones((batch_size, 1)))
        d_loss_fake = discriminator.train_on_batch([generated_images, conditioning_batch], np.zeros((batch_size, 1)))
        d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)

        # Train the generator
        g_loss = cgan_model.train_on_batch([input_batch, conditioning_batch], np.ones((batch_size, 1)))

        # Print progress
        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}, [D loss: {d_loss[0]} | D accuracy: {100 * d_loss[1]}] [G loss: {g_loss[0]} | G accuracy: {100 * g_loss[1]}]")
def generate_merged_image(generator, input_image, conditioning_image):
    input_image = np.expand_dims(input_image, axis=0)
    conditioning_image = np.expand_dims(conditioning_image, axis=0)

    generated_image = generator.predict([input_image, conditioning_image])

    # Post-process generated image if needed (e.g., rescale pixel values)

    return generated_image.squeeze()
```

I am trying to merge two landscape images as selected by user and show loading interface while the image is being merged and user has to click 'merged img' to get the merged img. I am encountering an issue while trying to load a saved TensorFlow Keras model using the `load_model` function. The error indicates that the specified model file, `full_path_to_cGAN_model.h5`, cannot be found. To address this, I need to ensure that the file path is accurate and that the model file is in the correct location. If the model file is saved with a different name or extension, I adjusted the filename accordingly. Additionally, I considered providing the full absolute path to the model file if it is not in the same directory as my script and double-checked the saving process to ensure that the model was saved correctly using the Keras `model.save` method.
Help regarding this is quite appreciated.
Its my first time making a project like this so there may be issues I am unable to detect.

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)